# Fedora 39 beta wrong resolution on Lenovo x280

Tags: fedora, gnome, resolution

I installed the Fedora 39 beta on my Lenovo ThinkPad X280 i5-8250U 1080P laptop but in the settings app and on the command line the screen resolution is shown as 1366x768 with a frame rate of ~ 60 Hz.

```
$ xrandr | less
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 280mm x 160mm
   1366x768      59.98*+
```

What could be causing Fedora not to detect the correct screen resolution of 1080P and how can I get Fedora to detect the correct resolution?

Comment: @ChanganAuto this is the exact laptop I purchased: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B09YHHV9K4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1. The specs say it's 1080p.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Lenovo-ThinkPad-i5-8250U-Windows-Professional/dp/B09YHHV9K4/ref=sr_1_3?crid=2JI5TJ5BSQ2TL&keywords=lenovo+x280&qid=1696769901&sprefix=lenovo+x280%2Caps%2C122&sr=8-3

Comment: Open a bug report here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks. I've opened an issue.

Comment: Please at least specify your kernel version in the bug report (you can edit it), e.g. `uname -a` and post `dmesg | grep i915` output.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks. I've provided the requested information in the issue: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/9480